# How to completely traverse a complex dictionary of unknown depth?

Tags: python, json, dictionary, python-2.7

Importing from `JSON` can get very complex and nested structures.
For example:

```
{u'body': [{u'declarations': [{u'id': {u'name': u'i',
                                       u'type': u'Identifier'},
                               u'init': {u'type': u'Literal', u'value': 2},
                               u'type': u'VariableDeclarator'}],
            u'kind': u'var',
            u'type': u'VariableDeclaration'},
           {u'declarations': [{u'id': {u'name': u'j',
                                       u'type': u'Identifier'},
                               u'init': {u'type': u'Literal', u'value': 4},
                               u'type': u'VariableDeclarator'}],
            u'kind': u'var',
            u'type': u'VariableDeclaration'},
           {u'declarations': [{u'id': {u'name': u'answer',
                                       u'type': u'Identifier'},
                               u'init': {u'left': {u'name': u'i',
                                                   u'type': u'Identifier'},
                                         u'operator': u'*',
                                         u'right': {u'name': u'j',
                                                    u'type': u'Identifier'},
                                         u'type': u'BinaryExpression'},
                               u'type': u'VariableDeclarator'}],
            u'kind': u'var',
            u'type': u'VariableDeclaration'}],
 u'type': u'Program'}
```

What is the recommended way to walk complex structures like the above?

Apart of a few list there are mostly dictionaries, the structure can become even more imbricated so I need a general solution.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You can use a recursive generator for converting your dictionary to flat lists.

```
def dict_generator(indict, pre=None):
    pre = pre[:] if pre else []
    if isinstance(indict, dict):
        for key, value in indict.items():
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                for d in dict_generator(value, pre + [key]):
                    yield d
            elif isinstance(value, list) or isinstance(value, tuple):
                for v in value:
                    for d in dict_generator(v, pre + [key]):
                        yield d
            else:
                yield pre + [key, value]
    else:
        yield pre + [indict]
```

It returns

```
[u'body', u'kind', u'var']
[u'init', u'declarations', u'body', u'type', u'Literal']
[u'init', u'declarations', u'body', u'value', 2]
[u'declarations', u'body', u'type', u'VariableDeclarator']
[u'id', u'declarations', u'body', u'type', u'Identifier']
[u'id', u'declarations', u'body', u'name', u'i']
[u'body', u'type', u'VariableDeclaration']
[u'body', u'kind', u'var']
[u'init', u'declarations', u'body', u'type', u'Literal']
[u'init', u'declarations', u'body', u'value', 4]
[u'declarations', u'body', u'type', u'VariableDeclarator']
[u'id', u'declarations', u'body', u'type', u'Identifier']
[u'id', u'declarations', u'body', u'name', u'j']
[u'body', u'type', u'VariableDeclaration']
[u'body', u'kind', u'var']
[u'init', u'declarations', u'body', u'operator', u'*']
[u'right', u'init', u'declarations', u'body', u'type', u'Identifier']
[u'right', u'init', u'declarations', u'body', u'name', u'j']
[u'init', u'declarations', u'body', u'type', u'BinaryExpression']
[u'left', u'init', u'declarations', u'body', u'type', u'Identifier']
[u'left', u'init', u'declarations', u'body', u'name', u'i']
[u'declarations', u'body', u'type', u'VariableDeclarator']
[u'id', u'declarations', u'body', u'type', u'Identifier']
[u'id', u'declarations', u'body', u'name', u'answer']
[u'body', u'type', u'VariableDeclaration']
[u'type', u'Program']
```

Comment: Of all the Solutions I am reading this is the easiest and works well :-) Thanks Bryukhanov Valentin

Comment: I wanted to also obtain indices in case of list/tuple childs. I achieved this by adding `enumerate` and do something like: `for i, v in enumerate(value): for d in dict_generator(v, pre + [key + f'[{i}]']):`

Comment: Full: https://hastebin.com/agiguhovuj.cs (it's Python, not C#)

Comment: it works great.  It produces a complete list of paths through the tree. one path per list.  mypaths=[*dict_generator(myjson)]

for path in mypaths:
    print(path)

Comment: what if i wanted to do this and put it back together after removing keys or items?

Comment: Sorry, didn't get your question. Put back what and where?

Comment: if there's empty dict (`{}`) as the leef value, the path is not included in the result. is it expected?

Comment: Yes, as I got from the question. It's easy to change if they are required in the result.

Answer (score 55):

If you only need to walk the dictionary, I'd suggest using a recursive `walk` function that takes a dictionary and then recursively walks through its elements. Something like this:

```
def walk(node):
    for key, item in node.items():
        if item is a collection:
            walk(item)
        else:
            It is a leaf, do your thing
```

If you also want to search for elements, or query several elements that pass certain criteria, have a look at the [jsonpath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) module.

Comment: This only works for directly nested dictionaries. In the example data structure, there were several dictionary values that were lists of other dictionaries. Some extra logic will be required to handle those (such as recursing inside a list comprehension or generator expression). To make things work right, you probably need to use your knowledge of the meaning of the data, such as the fact that all the dictionaries have a "type" key.

Comment: You should also be careful to check for cycles.  e.g.: foo = {}; foo['bar'] = foo  will blow you up. Your walk function should keep a list of, and not descend, objects it has seen. (you could pass the list to each successive call)

Comment: if item is a collection throws an error. what is your import statement

Answer (score 10):

Instead of writing your own parser, depending on the task, you could extend encoders and decoders from the standard library `json` module.

I recommend this especially if you need to encode objects belonging to custom classes into the json. If you have to do some operation which could be done also on a string representation of the json, consider also iterating JSONEncoder().iterencode

For both the reference is http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#encoders-and-decoders

Answer (score 7):

If you know the meaning of the data, you might want to create a `parse` function to turn the nested containers into a tree of objects of custom types. You'd then use methods of those custom objects to do whatever you need to do with the data.

For your example data structure, you might create `Program`, `VariableDeclaration`, `VariableDeclarator`, `Identifier`, `Literal` and `BinaryExpression` classes, then use something like this for your parser:

```
def parse(d):
    t = d[u"type"]

    if t == u"Program":
        body = [parse(block) for block in d[u"body"]]
        return Program(body)

    else if t == u"VariableDeclaration":
        kind = d[u"kind"]
        declarations = [parse(declaration) for declaration in d[u"declarations"]]
        return VariableDeclaration(kind, declarations)

    else if t == u"VariableDeclarator":
        id = parse(d[u"id"])
        init = parse(d[u"init"])
        return VariableDeclarator(id, init)

    else if t == u"Identifier":
        return Identifier(d[u"name"])

    else if t == u"Literal":
        return Literal(d[u"value"])

    else if t == u"BinaryExpression":
        operator = d[u"operator"]
        left = parse(d[u"left"])
        right = parse(d[u"right"])
        return BinaryExpression(operator, left, right)

    else:
        raise ValueError("Invalid data structure.")
```

Answer (score 6):

Maybe can help:

```
def walk(d):
    global path
      for k,v in d.items():
          if isinstance(v, str) or isinstance(v, int) or isinstance(v, float):
            path.append(k)
            print "{}={}".format(".".join(path), v)
            path.pop()
          elif v is None:
            path.append(k)
            ## do something special
            path.pop()
          elif isinstance(v, dict):
            path.append(k)
            walk(v)
            path.pop()
          else:
            print "###Type {} not recognized: {}.{}={}".format(type(v), ".".join(path),k, v)

mydict = {'Other': {'Stuff': {'Here': {'Key': 'Value'}}}, 'root1': {'address': {'country': 'Brazil', 'city': 'Sao', 'x': 'Pinheiros'}, 'surname': 'Fabiano', 'name': 'Silos', 'height': 1.9}, 'root2': {'address': {'country': 'Brazil', 'detail': {'neighbourhood': 'Central'}, 'city': 'Recife'}, 'surname': 'My', 'name': 'Friend', 'height': 1.78}}

path = []
walk(mydict)
```

Will produce output like this:

```
Other.Stuff.Here.Key=Value 
root1.height=1.9 
root1.surname=Fabiano 
root1.name=Silos 
root1.address.country=Brazil 
root1.address.x=Pinheiros 
root1.address.city=Sao 
root2.height=1.78 
root2.surname=My 
root2.name=Friend 
root2.address.country=Brazil 
root2.address.detail.neighbourhood=Central 
root2.address.city=Recife
```

Answer (score 6):

To walk/map over an entire JSON structure, you can use the following code:

```
def walk(node, key):
    if type(node) is dict:
        return {k: walk(v, k) for k, v in node.items()}
    elif type(node) is list:
        return [walk(x, key) for x in node]
    else:
        return YourFunction(node, key)

def YourFunction(node, key):
    if key == "yourTargetField":   # for example, you want to modify yourTargetField
        return "Modified Value"
    return node # return existing value
```

This will go through your entire json structure and run every leaf (endpoint key-value pair) through your function. Yourfunction returns the modified value. The entire walk function will give you a new, processed object, in order.

Answer (score 5):

If the accepted answer works for you, but you'd also like a full, ordered path with the numerical index of the nested arrays included, this slight variation will work:

```python
def dict_generator(indict, pre=None):
    pre = pre[:] if pre else []
    if isinstance(indict, dict):
        for key, value in indict.items():
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                for d in dict_generator(value,  pre + [key]):
                    yield d
            elif isinstance(value, list) or isinstance(value, tuple):
                for k,v in enumerate(value):
                    for d in dict_generator(v, pre + [key] + [k]):
                        yield d
            else:
                yield pre + [key, value]
    else:
        yield indict
```

Answer (score 4):

My more flexible version is as follows:

```py
def walktree(tree, at=lambda node: not isinstance(node, dict), prefix=(), 
                flattennode=lambda node:isinstance(node, (list, tuple, set))):
    """
    Traverse a tree, and return a iterator of the paths from the root nodes to the leaf nodes.
    tree: like '{'a':{'b':1,'c':2}}'
    at: a bool function or a int indicates levels num to go down. walktree(tree, at=1) equivalent to tree.items()
    flattennode: a bool function to decide whether to iterate at node value
    """
    if isinstance(at, int):
        isleaf_ = at == 0
        isleaf = lambda v: isleaf_
        at = at - 1
    else:
        isleaf = at
    if isleaf(tree):
        if not flattennode(tree):
            yield (*prefix, tree)
        else:
            for v in tree:
                yield from walktree(v, at, prefix, flattennode=flattennode)
    else:
        for k,v in tree.items():
            yield from walktree(v, at, (*prefix, k), flattennode=flattennode)
```

usage:

```py
> list(walktree({'a':{'b':[0,1],'c':2}, 'd':3}))
[('a', 'b', 0), ('a', 'b', 1), ('a', 'c', 2), ('d', 3)]
> list(walktree({'a':{'b':[0,1],'c':2}, 'd':3}, flattennode=lambda e:False))
[('a', 'b', [0, 1]), ('a', 'c', 2), ('d', 3)]
> list(walktree({'a':{'b':[0,1],'c':2}, 'd':3}, at=1))
[('a', {'b': [0, 1], 'c': 2}), ('d', 3)]
> list(walktree({'a':{'b':[0,{1:9,9:1}],'c':2}, 'd':3}))
[('a', 'b', 0), ('a', 'b', 1, 9), ('a', 'b', 9, 1), ('a', 'c', 2), ('d', 3)]
> list(walktree([1,2,3,[4,5]]))
[(1,), (2,), (3,), (4,), (5,)]
```

Comment: please consifer avoiding to post long answers that contains alot of code

Comment: @Khaled size of code, looks to me like the code is minimal for what is needed

Comment: This needs a blog post to explain it fully. I would actually love that

Answer (score 3):

Some addition to solution above (to handle json including lists)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import json

def walk(d):
   global path
   for k,v in d.items():
      if isinstance(v, str) or isinstance(v, int) or isinstance(v, float):
         path.append(k)
         print("{}={}".format(".".join(path), v)) 
         path.pop()
      elif v is None:
         path.append(k)
         # do something special
         path.pop()
      elif isinstance(v, list):
         path.append(k)
         for v_int in v:
            walk(v_int)
         path.pop()
      elif isinstance(v, dict):
         path.append(k)
         walk(v)
         path.pop()
      else:
         print("###Type {} not recognized: {}.{}={}".format(type(v), ".".join(path),k, v))

with open('abc.json') as f:
   myjson = json.load(f)

path = []
walk(myjson)
```

Answer (score 3):

A bit improved version of the accepted solution. If you're using Python3 (I hope you do) you can use [`yield from`](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-380-syntax-for-delegating-to-a-subgenerator) syntax that was introduced in Python 3.3. Also, `isinstance` as a second argument can accept tuple:

```
def dict_generator(adict, pre=None):
    pre = pre[:] if pre else []
    if isinstance(adict, dict):
        for key, value in adict.items():
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                yield from dict_generator(value, pre + [key])
            elif isinstance(value, (list, tuple)):
                for v in value:
                    yield from dict_generator(v, pre + [key])
            else:
                yield pre + [key, value]
    else:
        yield pre + [adict]
```

Iterative version (pretty similar if you're using generators):

```
def flatten(adict):
    stack = [[adict, []]]
    while stack:
        d, pre = stack.pop()
        if isinstance(d, dict):
            for key, value in d.items():
                if isinstance(value, dict):
                    stack.append([value, pre + [key]])
                elif isinstance(value, (list, tuple)):
                    for v in value:
                        stack.append([v, pre + [key]])
                else:
                    print(pre + [key, value])
        else:
            print(pre + [d])
```