# how to initialize list of lists of lists with unknown dimensions

Tags: python-3.x

Here d is a list of lists of lists with structure like this

```
[
    [

        [vocab[START], vocab["image1"], vocab["caption1"], vocab[END]],
        [vocab[START], vocab["image1"], vocab["caption2"], vocab[END]],
        ...
    ],
    ...
]
```

I don't know the dimensions already therefore I have problem in initializing, keeping an upper limit I could have used the xrange function like this

```
d=[[[[] for k in xrange(50)] for j in xrange(10)] for i in xrange(8769)]
```

but I'm working in Python3 and xrange is depreciated. The code goes like this

```
for i in range (len(t)):

  for j in range (len(t[i])):

   d[i][j][0]=vocab[START]

   for k in range(len(t[i][j])):

   if t[i][j][k] not in list(vocab.keys()):
    d[i][j][k+1]=vocab[UNK]
   else:
    d[i][j][k+1]=vocab[t[i][j][k]]
```

Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: what about `d=[[[[] for k in range(50)] for j in range(10)] for i in range(8769)]` ? `xrange` now is `range`.

Comment: please don't mix issues like `xrange` is deprecated with your other problem. It's really unclear, please [edit] your question to cut to the chase.

Comment: It looks a lot like json except with lists instead of dicts, maybe the ideas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12507206/python-how-to-completely-traverse-a-complex-dictionary-of-unknown-depth) could be helpful?

Comment: d=[[[[] for k in range(50)] for j in range(10)] for i in range(8769)] I did use it but like I said the dimensions are unknown and because of this I get a lot of empty lists[ ],which I do not want. I mentioned xrange because it's different in the fact that it creates lists lazily as per the demand unlike range in python3

Comment: How and why do you want to initialize if you dont know dimensions? You can always `.append()`

Comment: .append() gives me a 1D list which I do not want , I want a list in the 3D structure that I have mentioned above.