# How can I replace "None" as a dictionary value with an empty dictionary?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

Im parsing a complex json string and am working with nested dictionaries and some nested dic.get() functions in my class.

Instead of receiving a None when a higher level key doesn't exist, I would like to find an empty dictionary so that my code (dict.get()) keeps working.

Right now I would like to replace all dictionary values named None with an empty dictionary {}, but I didn't find any good solution how to do it.

So basically I want this:

```
{'a': {},
 'b': 'Text',
 'c': 5,
 'd': {'d1': {}}
```

but sadly have that:

```
{'a': None,
 'b': 'Text',
 'c': 5,
 'd': {'d1': None}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Other solution is to traverse the dictionary recursively and replace the `None` values:

```
def replace(d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        for k in d:
            if d[k] is None:
                d[k] = {}
            else:
                replace(d[k])
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        for v in d:
            replace(v)


d = {'a': None,
     'b': 'Text',
     'c': 5,
     'd': {'d1': None}}

replace(d)
print(d)
```

Prints:

```
{'a': {}, 'b': 'Text', 'c': 5, 'd': {'d1': {}}}
```

Comment: That works perfectly! Thank you very much. Tbh I don't understand the elif statement in detail. Didn't know that these kind of circular dependency is possible. The function can take a list of dictionaries, and if it fails its first part and it starts some kind of for loop?

Comment: @Christian `elif` just means `else if`. In my code I traverse the dictionary recursively (and handle a case if inside your dictionary is a list - however in your example you don't have any). You can search here on SO for examples/explanation how to search dictionary recursively. For example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12507206/how-to-completely-traverse-a-complex-dictionary-of-unknown-depth

Answer (score 2):

You can use the default value for the `get` method

```
dict.get("a", {})
```

Sample:

```
d = { 'b' : 1,
       'c' : { 'd': 2 } }
print (d.get('a', {}))
print (d.get('c', {}).get('a', {}))
print (d.get('x', {}).get('y', {}).get('z', {}))
```

output:

```
{}
{}
{}
```

Comment: Because I have a list of dictionaries in my string and I only want to replace those which are None. Some of them have true values. I also have a lot of keys and I don't want to explictly name them.

Comment: In your example: You've shown my problem: The c key won't work. If key c has no value, it would be None, and if it's None you can't do [...] .get('a', {}))

Comment: `d.get('x', {}).get('y', {}).get('z', {})` will work. Its simple then messing up the structure of the json

Comment: No, sadly it doesn't if the value exist as a None. It leads to: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'. It isn't recognized as null so that the condition for {} would be true.