# Update value within nested dict of arbitrary depth without changing the rest of the dict in Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, nested

So I have a nested dictionary in Python:

```
{'entry': {'definition': 'str',
       'endTime': 'str',
       'entryID': {'identifierType': 'str', 'identifierValue': 'str'},
       'instrument': {'FIB': {'FIBSpotSize': {'notes': 'str',
                                              'qualifier': 'str',
                                              'uncertainty': {'uncertaintyType': 'str',
                                                              'value': 'float'},
                                              'unit': 'str',
                                              'value': 'float'},
                              'angleToEBeam': {'notes': 'str',
                                               'qualifier': 'str',
                                               'uncertainty': {'uncertaintyType': 'str',
                                                               'value': 'float'},
                                               'unit': 'str',
                                               'value': 'float'},...
.
.
.
```

I want a way to simply access a specific key-value pair, given an arbitrarily long keys.

For instance, I want `entry.instrument.angleToEBeam.uncertainty.value` because I want to update the value of `value`. I want to write a function that takes a list of keys of arbitrary length, where the last key is the value I'd like to update, and the value which I'd like to set/update. I'm a bit confused on how to navigate/walk these nested dictionaries.

As an example of what I'm trying to do, I have a dict of values to update which looks like

```
{'entry.instrument.angleToEBeam.uncertainty.value': 2.23', ...}
```

And I'd like to feed this list into some function such that it updates the nested dict to have values instead of the expected type, here shown just for the `uncertainty` parameter:

```
{'entry': {'definition': 'str',
       'endTime': 'str',
       'entryID': {'identifierType': 'str', 'identifierValue': 'str'},
       'instrument': {'FIB': {'FIBSpotSize': {'notes': 'str',
                                              'qualifier': 'str',
                                              'uncertainty': {'uncertaintyType': 'str',
                                                              'value': 'float'},
                                              'unit': 'str',
                                              'value': 'float'},
                              'angleToEBeam': {'notes': 'str',
                                               'qualifier': 'str',
                                               'uncertainty': {'uncertaintyType': 'pct',
                                                               'value': 3.102},
                                               'unit': 'deg',
                                               'value': 2.23},...
.
.
.
```

Ultimately, these have to be exported as JSON files, hence the nested dictionary. Any ideas? Some related threads:

- [Update value of a nested dictionary of varying depth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232943/update-value-of-a-nested-dictionary-of-varying-depth)
- [How to completely traverse a complex dictionary of unknown depth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12507206/how-to-completely-traverse-a-complex-dictionary-of-unknown-depth)

But I couldn't figure out how to apply them to my situation, as they deal with flattening the dict entirely.

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13688108 Does this help?

Answer (score 1):

[JMESPath](https://pypi.org/project/jmespath/) is a powerful solution for querying a nested dict, but unfortunately doesn't seem to offer lvalue options (modification).

In the end, here is something built from first principles:

```py
def xupdate(dct, path, value, createkeys=False):
    if path:
        k, *path = path
        subdct = dct.get(k, {}) if createkeys else dct[k]
        return {**dct, **{k: xupdate(subdct, path, value)}}
    return value

def dotupdate(dct, dotmods, createkeys=False):
    for kdot, value in dotmods.items():
        dct = xupdate(dct, kdot.split('.'), value, createkeys)
    return dct
```

##### Example

```py
dct = {
    'entry': {
        'definition': 'str', 'endTime': 'str', 'entryID': {
            'identifierType': 'str', 'identifierValue': 'str'},
        'instrument': {
            'FIB': {
                'FIBSpotSize': {
                    'notes': 'str', 'qualifier': 'str', 'uncertainty': {
                        'uncertaintyType': 'str', 'value': 'float'},
                    'unit': 'str', 'value': 'float'},
                'angleToEBeam': {
                    'notes': 'str', 'qualifier': 'str', 'uncertainty': {
                        'uncertaintyType': 'str', 'value': 'float'},
                    'unit': 'str', 'value': 'float'}}}}}

dotmods = {
    'entry.instrument.FIB.angleToEBeam.uncertainty.value': 2.23,
    'entry.endTime': '2023-01-01',
}

>>> dotupdate(dct, dotmods)
{'entry': {'definition': 'str',
  'endTime': '2023-01-01',
  'entryID': {'identifierType': 'str', 'identifierValue': 'str'},
  'instrument': {'FIB': {'FIBSpotSize': {'notes': 'str',
     'qualifier': 'str',
     'uncertainty': {'uncertaintyType': 'str', 'value': 'float'},
     'unit': 'str',
     'value': 'float'},
    'angleToEBeam': {'notes': 'str',
     'qualifier': 'str',
     'uncertainty': {'uncertaintyType': 'str', 'value': 2.23},
     'unit': 'str',
     'value': 'float'}}}}}
```

##### Notes

1. `createkeys`: if `True`, keys that don't exist in the original `dict` (e.g. typos, incomplete path) are created. In the original question, there was a reference to the non-existent `'entry.instrument.angleToEBeam.uncertainty.value'` (missing `.FIB`); that would create the missing keys, which is probably not desired.
2. The order of the nested `dict` stays the same.
3. The original `dict` itself is not modified; the returned value is a semi-copy (a deep copy for the parts that are modified; unmodified sub-dicts are copied by reference).